# Decide if series convergent or divergent, and if convergent finding sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to decide if this series is convergent or not, and if it is to find its sum.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+3)(n+4)}$$
I think it is convergent as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(n+3)(n+4)}=0$$

From this point though I do not know how to obtain its sum.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: In general it's dangerous to assume that a series converges if the individual terms of a series approaches 0. For instance, the harmonic series famously diverges, despite the fact that $1/n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 n = 0 \text{ but } \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n \text{ diverges.}$ So your reason for thinking it converges is not good enough by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

- For convergence use comparison test.
- To obtain its sum use the identity $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n+3)(n+4)} = \frac{1}{n+3}-\frac{1}{n+4}$

**Note:** If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n}=0$ then it need not imply that $\sum a_{n}$ converges. Example $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$.